# OutputCache and different case for Accept-Encoding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, outputcache

I have an asp.net mvc app with OutputCache enabled with `varyByContentEncoding="gzip;deflate"` and it seems to work fine except for one client who keeps sending GZIP as Accept-Encoding (upper case) and my cache is ignored and regenerated for his every request.

How do I fight this guy so that his requests are treated as regular gzip for cache purposes ?

Comment: Just a workaround, have you tried `varyByContentEncoding="gzip;deflate;GZIP"`

Comment: @ArindamNayak just tried and now GZIP requests are served uncompressed. Gzipped version of the cache is not touched (which is good) but I don't think it uses uncompressed cache to serve GZIP reqs and instead goes to the controller action...

Comment: Some more time passed and now both - GZIP and gzip requests are getting gzipped cached version. However I feel like all this OutputCache + dynamic compresion integration are not working well together. Doesn't seem too reliable.